# Trying to upload a folder to google drive but denied permisions using C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have an console app I'm building in C#/

It has the flow

- Create a new folder  - working
- download files from a 3rd party using API - working
- add files to newly created folder - working
- upload newly populated folder to google drive - error - permission denied.

I semi know what I'm doing. The folder is created correctly and I know the upload process does work some of the time, because I can directly upload the downloaded .zip folder if I don't add them to the newly created folder.

The folder is being create in my bin/debug folder inside my program.
I have the Google API turned on and credentials also in the bin.

All the console writelines return the data I am looking for.

I must be missing some sort of set up permissions either when creating the new folder or trying to upload it. I have tried changing the `FileAccess.Read` to `.Write`... no luck.

The error I get with the code below is

> Error uploading artifact: Access to the path 'C:\Users\tbrockington\source\repos\GoogleDriveBuildController\GoogleDriveBuildController\bin\Debug\Silhouette Go 1221' is denied.

// Create folder

```
public static async Task CreateFolderToStoreDownloads()
{
    // Get the current directory where the executable is located
    string currentDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

    // Combine the current directory with the desired subfolder name
    string targetFolder = Path.Combine(currentDirectory, $"{TargetDirectory}");

    try
    {
        // Check if the folder already exists
        if (!Directory.Exists(targetFolder))
        {
            // If it doesn't exist, create it
            Directory.CreateDirectory($"{targetFolder}");
            Console.WriteLine("Empty folder created successfully.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The folder already exists.");

            string newID = $"{EntryArgsName} {BuildId} 1";
            string newTargetFolder = Path.Combine(currentDirectory, $"{newID}");

            TargetDirectory = newID;

            Directory.CreateDirectory(newTargetFolder);
            Console.WriteLine($"New folder name: {newID}");
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

// Upload to google drive

```
public static async Task UploadFilesToGoogleDrive()
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Uploading Directory: {TargetDirectory}");

    string credentialsPath = "credentials.json";
    // string folderId = "1Ro77nizxMbe_5RfsyLCPsIviHMJXiDd6";

    string filePath = $"{TargetDirectory}";

    GoogleCredential credential;

    using (var stream = new FileStream(credentialsPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped(new[]
        {
            DriveService.ScopeConstants.DriveFile
        });
    }

    try
    {

        var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Google DRIVE upload app"
        });


        var fileMetaData = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
        {
            Name = Path.GetFileName(filePath),
        };

        FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;

        using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            request = service.Files.Create(fileMetaData, stream, "");
            request.Upload();
        }

        var uploadedFile = request.ResponseBody;

        // Console.WriteLine($"FILE: {fileMetaData.Name} - uploaded with {uploadedFile.Id}");

        Console.WriteLine("Upload Completed");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");

        Console.WriteLine($"Error uploading artifact: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

I have check my strings. Turned off any antivirus. Am on a dev PC.
Its no use manually updating permissions to a folder because this all needs to run with no human assistance.

I tried adding this which was recommended by chatGPT but to no help

```
public static void RequestWritePermissions(string directoryPath)
{
    // Define a new directory security and add a rule that allows write access
    DirectorySecurity directorySecurity = new DirectorySecurity();
    directorySecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(Environment.UserName, FileSystemRights.Write, AccessControlType.Allow));

    // Set the directory security to the specified path
    Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath, directorySecurity);
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: stackoverflow whines when you are not putting enough code and now this